# How to hyperlink a Text in a column using VBA/Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have the below table (example) with thousand of rows that consists of a column of Request ID and a column of Request ID URL.
How can I hyperlink the Request ID URL into the Request ID text column using VBA or Macro, so that when people click on the ID it will be redirected to the URL.

I do not wish to add another column and use the HYPERLINK formula like =HYPERLINK(B2,A2). I wish the link can directly embedded into the existing

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2018/07/02/hyperlink-formula-events/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my own questions by writing a very basic code snippet using Excel Script Lab.
Just need to figure out how do get a dynamic range in Script Lab, as the Excel sheet range might be various from time to time...
Code as per below.

```
async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    
    let reqID = sheet.getRange("A2:A6");
    reqID.load("values");

    let reqURL = sheet.getRange("B2:B6");
    reqURL.load("values");

    await context.sync();

    for(let i=0;i<reqID.values.length;i++){
      let cellRange = reqID.getCell(i,0);
      let cellText = reqID.values[i][0];
      let cellURL = reqURL.values[i][0];

      let hyperlink ={
        textToDisplay: cellText,
        address: cellURL
      }
      cellRange.hyperlink = hyperlink;
    }

  });
}
```